# How can I display local popup images in a leaflet map exported as HTML from R?

Tags: r, leaflet

I can display the images as popups on the map within R Studio, but when I export the map to HTML, the images are greyed out. The map and circles markers are there, just not the images when I click on the circle markers. Here is the code I'm using:

```
data <- data.frame(lat = as.numeric(c("39.16", "39.46")),   long = as.numeric(c("-76.62", "-76.63")))

images <- c("C:/Users/local/img1.png",
            "C:/Users/local/img2.png")

map <- leaflet(data) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(fillOpacity = 0.8, radius = 5,
                   lng = ~long, lat =~lat,  popup = popupImage(images))
```